# Java Nashorn using webEngine events

Tags: javascript, java, nashorn

I'm trying to process events from a webEngine in Nashorn. The following code doesn't print anything or indicate in any other way that the "load" event or any other event from the webEngine is triggering anything.

```
#!/usr/bin/jjs -fx
engine = (v=new(s=javafx.scene).web.WebView).engine
content_dir = __DIR__.replace('./','html/');
page = 'file://' + content_dir + 'index.html';
engine.onAction = function(){print("page loaded");};
engine.load(page);
$STAGE.scene=new s.Scene(v);
```

The page in this example loads just fine. I just can't seem to get any events from the engine. I've examined how it's done in Java but according to the docs in Nashorn you only need to set onAction as above. So I'm confused.

Answer (score 1):

"engine" property of WebView of type WebEngine (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/web/WebEngine.html). That class does not have a bean-style method named "setOnAction". There is only setOnAlert - which is invoked when WebView's JavaScript engine evaluates JS "alert" call. So, your property set "onAction" is ignored [setting non-existent property of a Java object]. You've to use "loadWorker" state to track load events from WebView's JS engine.

You may want to look at this sample code for interaction between WebView's JS engine and nashorn JS engine:

http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9/dev/nashorn/file/e4283eeb182c/samples/browser_dom.js

Comment: thank you. I got it to work. Now trying to get some sort of message passing between environments going but that's a separate problem.